# Running a MVN analysis in R for multivariate normality assumption

Tags: r, maven

I am running a MVN analysis but I am stuck with an error after this code:

```
library(MVN)
mnvb1 <- mvn(data = b1, mvnTest = "mardia")
```

> *Error in mvn(data = b1, mvnTest = "mardia", na.action = na.omit) : 
>     unused argument (na.action = na.omit)*

I have few NA in my dataframe but MVN should be able to deal with this without any additional code.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest to add source code which is generating the problem to question as now it's really hard to find out what's the problem

Comment: If you still have not solve your issue, you can update MVN package to 5.7 version (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MVN/index.html). This will solve your problem.